# Как пробежать циклом FOR каждый элемент в матрице (двумерном массиве) PYTHON

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Пытался разобраться как это сделать, представление есть, но написать не получается, как только не пробовал и все равно неправильно работает, суть в том, что нужно найти кол-во отриц., положит., и нулевых элементов в матрице.
Не пользовался nump и хочу сделать без него, размер матрицы формируется пользователем,и заполняется случайными числами из диапазона который вводит пользователь, это прекрасно работает, а вот как дальше пробегать по каждому элементу и сделать какое-либо условие не понял.
!Поправка! понял как пройтись по элементам проверив на print('dsad') и когда вводил матрицу 2х2 то есть 4 элемента 4 раза выводило dsad, но не пойму как все таки найти положительные или отрицательные, сделал тестовый код, в условии что-то не так, не пойму что именно сравнивать с нулём. Заранее спасибо!

```py
import random
l,r=map(int,input('Введите диапазон чисел для заполнения матрицы: ').split())
def matrix(x, y):
    return [[random.randint(l,r) for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]
n,k=map(int,input('Введите кол-во строк и столбцов матрицы: ').split())
for i in range(len(matrix(k,n))):
    for j in range(len(matrix(k,n)[i])):
        print(matrix(k,n)[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
pos=0
neg=0
zero=0
for i in range(len(matrix(k,n))):
    for j in range(len(matrix())):
        if j>0:
            pos+=1
        elif j<0:
            neg+=1
        else:
            zero+=1
if pos>0:
    print('Кол-во положительных элементов матрицы: ',pos)
if neg>0:
    print('Кол-во отрицательных элементов матрицы: ',neg)
if zero>0:
    print('Кол-во нулевых элементов матрицы:',zero)
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Исправьте ваш вопрос, изменив картинку на блок кода в текстовом формате. Для этого нажмите [edit] под самим вопросом. Иначе, вы вряд ли найдете ответ и понимание от активных членов сообщества. Из картинки никто не будет переписывать код

Comment: для работы с матрицами начните уже использовать модуль `numpy` - сэкономите себе кучу времени и нервов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В лоб

```py
matrix  = [[-1,2,3],[0,5,6], [-7,8,9]]

negative = 0
zeros = 0
positive = 0

for i in matrix:
    for j in i:
        if j == 0:
            zeros += 1
        elif j > 0:
            positive += 1
        else:
            negative += 1
```

Перебирать по индексам строк и столбцов в данном случае нет смысла, все равно нужно пробежаться по всем элементам

Устал я с вами в комментариях бороться. Ваши ошибки

1. Не надо каждый раз вызывать функцию `matrix(k, n)`, поскольку вы плодите совершенно не связанные друг с другом объекты, которые вам по сути не нужны, кроме того, что вы забираете оттуда длины. Вызовите один раз, результат работы поместите в переменную, и вот с ней и работайте

   ```py
   matrix_variable = matrix(k,n)
   ```
2. Вам не нужны `range` и `len` поскольку вы перебираете все члены матрицы. Для того чтобы перебрать каждый элемент вам нужен только `for` и итерируемый объект

В итоге ваш код

```py
# здесь ваш ввод, определение функции для matrix и проч
matrix_variable  = matrix(k, n)

negative = 0
zeros = 0
positive = 0

for i in matrix_variable:
    for j in i:
        if j == 0:
            zeros += 1
        elif j > 0:
            positive += 1
        else:
            negative += 1
```

Comment: Попробовал так только у меня матрица, которая в процессе формируется, поэтому сделал for i in matrix(k,n) и т.д. ,но работает неправильно, какие то случайные числа выдает

Comment: Если я просто напишу matrix , то ошибка будет , такого параметра не существует, потому что у меня функция matrix{x,y)  с помощью которой с клавиатуры вводится кол-во строк и столбцов

Comment: Я впервые на этом сайте что-либо пишу, поэтому не совсем понимаю как в комментарий добавить скрин

Comment: import random
l,r=map(int,input('Введите диапазон чисел для заполнения матрицы: ').split())
def matrix(x, y):
    return [[random.randint(l,r) for i in range(x)] for j in range(y)]
n,k=map(int,input('Введите кол-во строк и столбцов матрицы: ').split())
for i in range(len(matrix(k,n))):
    for j in range(len(matrix(k,n)[i])):
        print(matrix(k,n)[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
pos=0
neg=0
zero=0
for i in range(len(matrix(k,n))):
    for j in range(len(matrix())):
        if j>0:
            pos+=1
        elif j<0:
            neg+=1
        else:
            zero+=1

Comment: Извините, что так долго разбирался как его выделить и тд. уже добавил.

Comment: @ЮнусЮсупов я обновил ответ, далее читайте и разбирайтесь, Но за код текстом я вам + поставлю)(

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь) Извиняюсь за предоставленные неудобства, в дальнейшем буду знать.

Comment: @ЮнусЮсупов это и была моя цель. Не забывайте оценивать ответы на ваши вопросы и принимать, наиболее подходящие.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо)

Comment: @ЮнусЮсупов на здоровье)

Answer (score 0):

например вот так:

```
w = 100
h = 50

m = [[1 for j in range(h)] for i in range(w)]

for j in range(len(m)):
    for i in range(len(m[j])):
        value = m[j][i]
```